# Is there still a way to buy or change Ethereum classic?

Tags: ethereum-classic

I'm still looking for a possibility to change my ETH (after HF) to ETC or directly buy ETC. Do anyone know what is the most convenient way?

Comment: imho, poloniex is easiest. quick turn around and market prices

Comment: I second Poloniex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Website shapeshift.io will exchange coins of many flavors at current market rates.